# How to look for try blocks that don't have a catch block?

Tags: c#, vb.net, try-finally

I have a big solution that don't have a standard way for error handling.
Lately I found many methods that have try/finally block. No catch block.
How I found all occurrences of something like this ?

Comment: Why do you wish to find all occurrences of this?

Comment: Why searching for "finally" is not enough?

Comment: Search for `finally` and look to see if there's a `catch` block before it?

Comment: use the `Search` and do it at a solution level

Comment: I actually use `finally` *more often* than I use `catch` (although I use `using` more often than either) : most exceptions, the most appropriate thing is to *let them bubble* - but you still need to clean up

Comment: @krisdyson There are some leaking exception. Exceptions that occur and nothing logged or even handled.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov searchinfor finally will return all finally blocks weather there is a catch block or not. Searching for try will not do the job (for the same reason).

Comment: @MattBurland you absolutely right. The issue is, the solution is huge and manual inspection of the search result will be time consuming.

Comment: @DJKRAZE yes. but I need a good search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`try` does not necessarily means the block can throw an error. It is sometimes syntactical sugar for lazy programmers.

**Example**:

Say you wish to `return` a value and then modify that value. You can write this as:

```
public int Foo () {
    int old = this.value;
    this.value = 5;
    return old;
}
```

But a more convenient way is:

```
public int Foo () {
    try {
        return this.value;
    } finally {
        this.value = 5;
    }
}
```

You can argue the second implementation is longer, but in general, this is not true. And furthermore it prevents one from storing `old` values explicitly. The second implementation is more readable and is less error-prone since it states what the programmer intended.

One can argue that this makes the `try` keyword more ambiguous than was probably intended in the first place. A better keyword was probably more appropriate...

---

As far as I am aware, there is no easy way to check for `try` blocks with no `catch` block. You can hope a `Regex` will find **most** of the instance (for instance using `@"try\d*{[^}]*}\d*finally\d{[^}]*}`, but say there is an additional scope in the `try` or `finally` block, then the `Regex` will not detect this. The easiest is probably copying the context-free grammar of C#/Vb.Net and then at the construction of a `try`/`catch`/`finally` block do the proper checking and print in case it does not contain a `catch` block.